# Is it possible to use a blade template for a Vue component?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have a blade template in which all data is linked together. Now I prefer to have the HTML separated from the JS for better syntax coloring and preventing compilation when changing non-Vue HTML elements or CSS.

I've read about using `@{{ vue_var }}` and `v-for` inside Blade to reference Vue variables.

Would it be possible to load this blade template into Vue instead of defining the template above using `<template></template>`?

Comment: Please add an example of your code in order to clarify what your target behaviour should be like. In general you can define a template using blade and you can pass data you have accessible in blade to a vue component. But it's somewhat unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: you can check this tutorial https://vegibit.com/how-to-use-vuejs-with-laravel-blade/

Answer (score 0):

Vue components are written in javascript and blade templates are written with php. I think it's not possible.